# CGAL::BASIC_viewer not found, but Qt5 is installed regularly

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cgal

[image: Cmake-gui]

[image: Cmake message]

I found some discussion online, but the most problem with CGAL::BAISC_viewer is "not define".

In my case CGAL_Qt5 can be found regularly.
However, in CMakeLists.txt

```
target_link_libraries(draw_polygon PUBLIC CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer)
```

cannot link CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer properly.

Cmake show the message

```
Target "draw_polygon" links to target "CGAL::CGAL_Basic_viewer" but the
```

Does anyone know how to deal with this problem ?

I've tried re-installed Qt5, CGAL package.
Also, I've installed GMP, MPFR, Boost.
Some discussion with Qt5_Basic_viewer is not helpful for my cases.
I hope there would be someone who has same experience able to help me.

Comment: It seems you mix two different versions of CGAL. Your CGAL_DIR is in /usr/lib/... but your compile example from your home directory. The problem could be that the two versions of CGAL are different?

Comment: The file I compiled is an example download from CGAL official website. There is no CGAL header file.  Everything in that folder is some cpp file and CMakelist.txt.

Comment: What is the version of CGAL installed on your system? You should use the same version for CGAL and for the example your compile. 
I suggest to remove the CGAL version installed on your system, and use only a version of cgal clone from the github repository.

Comment: Alternative: comment out the `target_link_libraries` and add the line `#define CGAL_USE_BASIC_VIEWER` as the first line in the `draw_polygon.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. For me the problem was that the version of the examples (`CGAL-5.6` in my case) did not match the CGAL version that was installed using the package manager using `sudo apt-get install libcgal-dev`.

Checking the installed CGAL version using CMake as follows (include in your `CMakelists.txt`):

```
find_package(CGAL COMPONENTS Qt5)
message("CGAL Version: ${CGAL_VERSION}")
```

gave me `CGAL Version: 5.00.2.100`, which apparently did not match the version of the examples.

I solved the issue by downloading the appropriate version of the examples (which you can obtain from release [CGAL-5.0](/https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/tag/releases%2FCGAL-5.0)).

Comment: I've solved this problem by matching the version. However, my basic viewer is totally blank. Nothing shows in my window.